# Assigning a variable for each item in list [Python]

Tags: python

I am trying to assign a variable to each item in a list, not knowing how long the list is. I have read a decent amount on this website of solutions, and I'm confused about whether or not to use exec or what to even use. An example of what I want is:

```
list = ['123', '1345', '521'] # Not always going to be 3, I don't know how long the list will be.

var1 = list[0]
var2 = list[1]
var3 = list[2]

check = input(f'Option 1: {var1}\nOption 2: {var2}\nOption 3: {var3}') # I want to make an input so I can chose what item I want to interact with.

if check == '1':
    #interact with option 1
    # Example: print(var1)
elif check == '2':
    #interact with option 2
    # Example: print(var2)
elif check == '3':
    #interact with option 3
    # Example: print(var3)
else:
    print('Invalid Option.')
```

Above is an example of what I am looking to do. A lot of people say dynamic variables are bad, or just not good to use? I'm not sure what to really do to achieve this.

Comment: do not use `list` as variable name, its already being taken by `list()` built in that you shadow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to the others, you can build your input string by iterating through the list with `enumerate` to keep track of the option index

```
l = ['123', '1345', '521']

# build input string
input_str = ''
for i, itm in enumerate(l, 1):
    input_str += f'Option {i}: {itm}\n'

check = int(input(input_str))

if not check or check > len(l):
    print('Invalid Option.')
else:
    option = l[check - 1]
    # interact with option
    print(option)
```

Comment: This works thank you! this is exactly what I was trying to do. I can't mark it as the answer because I don't have 15 posts or whatever, but once I do, I will. Thanks!

Comment: @chickennugget982 you should be able to accept it by clicking on the green checkmark

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
if check == '1':
    #interact with option 1
    # Example: print(var1)
elif check == '2':
    #interact with option 2
    # Example: print(var2)
elif check == '3':
    #interact with option 3
    # Example: print(var3)
```

You can write

```
# interact with option 'check'
check = int(check)
print(list[check])
```

That's what lists/arrays are for...

Edit: in this case `print(list[check-1])` as list index starts from 0.

Comment: Be sure to convert `check` to an `int` though!

Answer (score 0):

Note: Avoid using `list` as a variable name

> It's already being taken by list() built in that you shadow

You can first check the `check` is bigger then length of mylist.
Then, you print the item of the `check`th item. else, print `Invalid Option`

And, you have to `int()` your input.

Like this:

```
mylist = ['123', '1345', '521'] # Not always going to be 3, I don't know how long the list will be.

var1 = mylist[0]
var2 = mylist[1]
var3 = mylist[2]

check = int(input(f'Option 1: {var1}\nOption 2: {var2}\nOption 3: {var3}')) # I want to make an input so I can chose what item I want to interact with.
if check > len(mylist)
    print(mylist[check])
else:
    print('Invalid Option.')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

#### Code Syntax

```
lista = ['123', '1345', '521']

### Intializing list of tuples ###

list_of_tuples = [(key+1, value) for key, value in enumerate (lista)]   # we've to create list of tuples to save the values with its indexes

### Slicing list of tuples ###

_ = list(map(lambda tuply: print(f"option {tuply[0]}: {tuply[1]}\n"), list_of_tuples))   # we're generating over our listof tuples but we've to assign this iteration to a variable not to spend all the values to the option slicing and leave the list of tuples empty.

print('-'*40)

check = int(input("Enter your option: "))

### Check you option depending on your indentation input ###
if check == 1:
    print(list_of_tuples[check-1][1])
elif check == 2:
    print(list_of_tuples[check-1][1])
elif check == 3:
    print(list_of_tuples[check-1][1])
else:
    print('Invalid Option.')
```

#### OUTPUT

**Senario 1**

```
option 1: 123

option 2: 1345

option 3: 521

----------------------------------------
Enter your option: 1
123

[Program finished]
```

**Senario 2**

```
option 1: 123

option 2: 1345

option 3: 521

----------------------------------------
Enter your option: 5
Invalid Option.

[Program finished]
```